# CakePHP 3: DebugKit is not enabled

Tags: debugging, cakephp-3.0

I downloaded the `DebugKit` plugin using:

```
php composer.phar require --dev cakephp/debug_kit "~3.0"
```

But it still shows warning in `error.log` and `DebugKit` is not working:

> Warning: DebugKit not enabled. You need to either install
>   pdo_sqlite, or define the "debug_kit" connection name

So how to define `debug_kit` connection name in `app.php` and how to enable debugkit??

Comment: Why don't you just install/enable `pdo_sqlite`? How to create connections is explained in the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#database-configuration

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=install+enable+pdo+sqlite And no, with PDO SQlite enabled, there is no need to manually define a separate connection for Debug Kit, the plugin will create one itself.

Comment: But if you don't want to use SQLite but another database, you have to declare your connection like the default connection in Datasources but named debug_kit

Comment: thanks it works without pdo_sqlite install..only define debug_kit in app.php

Comment: Please create an answer with the working solution

Answer (score 7):

> Installing and enabling `pdo_sqlite` from `Terminal`

For `PHP5.6`

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-sqlite3
```

For `PHP7`

```
sudo apt-get install php7*-sqlite3
```

After installation, Restart Apache Server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Note:** `php5.6-sqlite3` = `{YourPhpVersion}-{SqliteVersion}`

Comment: I Installed php7.2-sqlite3 but DebugKit still doesn't load and logs the error: Warning: DebugKit not enabled. You need to either install pdo_sqlite, or define the "debug_kit" connection name.

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts Check your current PHP version using terminal `php -v`. If the version is OK then restart your server. This should work.

Answer (score 3):

In app file:

```
.../config/app.php
```

in option "Datasources": create new sub option like this:

```
'debug_kit' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => DB_HOST,
        'port' => DB_PORT,

        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => DB_ACC,
        'password' => DB_PASS,
        'database' => DB_NAME,

        //'encoding' => 'utf8mb4',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ]
```

Save file app and refresh your website. Done.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what's needed. I put it in my `app_local.php` -- it's ridiculous that it's _still_ missing from the framework even now.